# How to analyze/group by text in power bi

Tags: group-by, powerbi

I'm quite new to power bi and wonder how to analyze interests of persons over time.
My table looks like:

User, InterestedIn, Date
UserA, Sports, 2018-10-02
UserB, Sports, 2018-10-05
UserC, Reading, 2018-10-05
UserC, Math, 2018-11-03
....

I know want to make visualisations about how the interests develop over a period of time. I therefore related the date column to my date table, but when i drag the "InterestedIn" and Date Column into a visual im not able to generate a meaningfull output.

Do i have to add like a "Count"-Column with numeric values?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: For us to be able to help, you need to show/tell us more. What is the output you are getting and what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to use the Modeling ribbon to add a Count measure e.g.

`# Interests = COUNTROWS ( Interests )`

and/or

`# Users = DISTINCTCOUNT ( Interests[User] )`

Then add that to **Values** well or similar (depends on which visuals you want).